# STRANGE!!! Not able to create new opportunity record from UI and class

Tags: sharing

getting error while creating record from UI in salesforce..

**Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.**

CHECKED everything but no luck all setting are proper and not changed.
Yesterday it was working fine but suddenly today i am not able to create opportunity record.
And also not able to do any insert,update,delete operations.

Comment: Did you change class or VF page API version yesterday? Sometimes this error comes up for this reason - rare case but possible.

Comment: no but i deployed two classes yesterday

Comment: yester one more change i did.....one package i suspended....do this cause error?

Comment: Get 1000% sure that is not a permissions issue first... if you are, then I wouldn't exclude anything as cause, as I've seen the "Insufficient Privileges" error popping up at random also for non-permission related issues (and they were mostly API version issues as prev said). If you have to do this painful investigation,  you may start start from the triggers you have defined on the Opportunity object, keeping an eye in particular if there are calls to a recently updated class, or "suspended" package component. Again, get 1000% sure that is not a permissions issue first... best of luck to you.